# plotly graph doesn't show up

Tags: shiny, plotly, shinydashboard

I'm using shiny and I can't get a plotly graph to appear. It was appearing before, I don't know what changed.

MRE:

global.r (or put this into server.r)

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
```

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$plotlyGraph <- renderPlotly({
    input$regraph
    print("graphing...")
    return(plot_ly(list(blank = 0)))
  })

})
```

ui.r

```
    dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "The Title"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        actionButton("regraph", "graph again")
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        box(plotlyOutput("plotlyGraph"))
      )
    )
```

R version 3.2.3

shiny version 13.0

shinydashbaord 0.5.1

plotly 2.0.16

empty environment

I noticed that when I run the above code, I get an error 
`Error in gregexpr(calltext, singleline, fixed = TRUE) : regular expression is invalid UTF-8.`

Upon further investigation with `debug(gregexpr)`, I see this

```
Called from: inherits(x, "ggplot")
debugging in: gregexpr(calltext, singleline, fixed = TRUE)
debug: {
    if (!is.character(text)) 
        text <- as.character(text)
    .Internal(gregexpr(as.character(pattern), text, ignore.case, 
        perl, fixed, useBytes))
}
Browse[2]> text
[1] "function (x) inherits(x, \"ggplot\")"
```

not sure what to make of that. Is there really some under-the-hood code that's supposed to be modifying a string that is later evaluated to a function?

I found another program I have where the plotly graph renders fine. gregrexpr() is never called. Looking at the generated HTML, the problematic one has this under style

```
width: 100%; height: 400px; visibility: hidden;
```

whereas the visible ones have

```
width: 100%; height: 400px; visibility: inherit;
```

so I imagine this is related (though causation direction is unknown...)

Comment: Does it occur when you set a breakpoint ? There's such a problem with RStudio: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/j-qY_rIBpkQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
renderPlotly({
return(plot_ly(x))
})
```

is broken.

```
renderPlotly(plot_ly(x))
```

works.

To do more work before rendering the plotly, do something like

```
renderPlotly(yourFunctThatGeneratesAPlotly(input$Whatever))
```