# Error in renderPlot (shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a stange error in **renderPlot** section. Here is the example (extract from the main script):

**ui.R**

```
 splitLayout(cellWidths = 600, plotOutput("box_plot_best", width = "80%", height = "200px"))
```

**server.r**

```
output$box_plot_best <- renderPlot({

          boxplot(c(1:100), width=4, horizontal= TRUE, staplewex = 1, axes=FALSE, main=("Theoretical boxplot"))     
          abline(v = mean(c(1:100)), col = "red") 
          dev.off()

        })
```

Earlier everything was ok - the boxplot was generated.
but now a strange error is generated:

> Error in gregexpr(calltext, singleline, fixed = TRUE) :
>     regular expression is invalid UTF-8
>   Browse[2]> c
>   Warning: Error in grDevices::recordPlot: no current device to record from
>   Stack trace (innermost first):
>       89: 
>       78: plotObj
>       77: origRenderFunc
>       76: output$box_plot_abs
>        1: runApp
>   Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
>   Error in gregexpr(calltext, singleline, fixed = TRUE) :
>     regular expression is invalid UTF-8

I have found a [similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35463404/plotly-graph-doesnt-show-up) and solution but not exectly my case
I would be gratefull for your hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the issue is with the `dev.off()` line. Once you remove that it works.