# No results for plotly/shiny in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, plotly, ggplotly

The question has confused me for about 1 months or more. When I try to get a plotly or shiny object with the package in Rstudio, nothing appeared in the Viewer window.

For the plotly, I can get the correct result in Rgui, while it it doesn't work for shiny even if I just want to get the simplest example result.

For example, when I run the following code:

```
library(shiny)
runExample("01_hello")
```

or:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
p<-ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

I just got the blank window in the Viewer for Rstudio and no error message as following.

[So sorry I can just put a link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbtUx.jpg)

I've tried everything I could, and I've updated the Rstudio, the package but nothing helped. I remember that it worked half years ago and I really couldn't understand what happened then.

I've seen the question [No plot displayed with plotly in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392544/no-plot-displayed-with-plotly-in-shiny) before, but it doesn't work too.

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936  LC_CTYPE=Chinese 
(Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plotly_4.8.0.9000 ggplot2_3.1.0     shiny_1.2.0
```

Any suggestions are very welcome, thanks!

Comment: read the community guide lines about how to post a reproducible example

Comment: It might not be your issue, but when displaying plots in shiny you should not forget to cover your plotting command in a `print()` function. In other words, e.g. try `plot <- ggplot(x, ...)` and then `print(plot)` instead of using the plotting command alone. As I said, this might solve your problem, but as your example isn't very reproducible it's more or less a guess.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the mistake before and I've copied my code there and I hope anyone can help me.